# First time odd message

Tags: bug

When I logged in today, I got this odd message:
[image]
I had cleared out cookies yesterday, so that might be related.  But I’ve done that before without this message.  Bug?  Glitch?

And then when I came to Meta, I got this:
[image]
So perhaps the certificate is not registered.

Not sure bug tag is really appropriate …

Comment: I get the first error from time to time and narrowed it down to using aVPN. Some websites blacklist IP addresses from out of the area or from a known list of problematic IPs or known VPN providers. The second one, no idea.

Comment: Not using a VPN, and it did log me in, so SE is not blacklisting me.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot shows the address as *meta.apple.stackexchange.com*.
The correct site address is *apple.meta.stackexchange.com*.

The address was changed a year or so ago.  Check your bookmarks, they may be out of date.